# Access VBScript ADODB.Command giving "Arguments are of wrong type" error

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have a VBscript that's opening up an Access DB, and I need to create a query from one of the tables, then export the table. I need to create the query because I need to format the number columns since in the DB they have like 10 decimal places but when exported only have 2. I need all 10. I don't control this Access DB, instead I download it so asking the source to make this query isn't an option.

The error with the below is: "ADODB.Command: Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another." what am I missing?

```
Dim oAccess
Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("dbfile here")

Dim oQry
Set oQry = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

oQry.ActiveConnection = oAccess.CurrentProject.Connection
oQry.CommandType = 1
oQry.CommandText = "create view qryTable as select * from table"
oQry.Execute

Set oQry = Nothing
Set oAccess = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving `.ActiveConnection` a string value works for me.

```
oQry.ActiveConnection = oAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString
```

Beware if the *Provider* in that string is "*Jet.OLEDB*" and you're using 64 bit Windows, you must run the script in 32 bit mode; I used the version of `cscript.exe` from `\Windows\SysWOW64`.

However I'm unsure why you open an Access application instance and then create and execute an `ADODB.Command`.  Perhaps that was an attempt to re-use the application's `CurrentProject.Connection` so that you wouldn't need to create one from scratch.

Whatever the reason was, if you have an Access instance anyway, you don't need the `ADODB.Command`.  Just use the `.Execute` method from `CurrentProject.Connection`.

```
Dim oAccess, sSql

Set oAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("dbfile here")

sSql = "create view qryTable as select * from [table]"
oAccess.CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sSql

Set oAccess = Nothing
```